# Type inference not working as expected for functions defined as object properties

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

I have a function that accepts a `payload` and a configuration `options` object as its arguments.  The `options` will contain two functions that will be called such that the result of `function1` is passed as the argument to `function2` however I cannot seem to figure out how to get the type inference to flow through correctly when these functions are specified as properties of an object.

For example:

```js
function inferenceDoesntWork<
  TFirstFn extends () => any,
  TSecondFn extends (arg: ReturnType<TFirstFn>) => any
>(
  options: {
    firstFunction: TFirstFn,
    secondFunction: TSecondFn,
  }
) {
  const firstResult = options.firstFunction();
  return options.secondFunction(firstResult)
}
console.log("not working", inferenceDoesntWork(
  {
    firstFunction: function fn1() { return true },
    secondFunction: function fn2(arg) {
      // INCORRECTLY INFERRED AS ANY
      return arg
    }
  }
))
```

If the function is written such that the two inner functions are specified as the outer functions arguments, then the type inference works as expected:

```js
function inferenceWorks<
  TFirstFn extends () => any,
  TSecondFn extends (arg: ReturnType<TFirstFn>) => any
>(

  firstFunction: TFirstFn,
  secondFunction: TSecondFn

) {
  const firstResult = firstFunction();
  return secondFunction(firstResult)
}

console.log("working", inferenceWorks(
  function fn1() { return true },
  function fn2(arg) {
    // CORRECTLY INFERRED AS BOOLEAN
    return arg
  },
))
```

As [@TypescriptTutor points out](https://twitter.com/TypescriptTutor/status/1236010849090732034), however, if specified as an arrow function.. it *does* infer correctly:

```js
function arrowFunctionsWork<
  TFirstFn extends () => any,
  TSecondFn extends (arg: ReturnType<TFirstFn>) => any
>(
  options: {
    firstFunction: TFirstFn,
    secondFunction: TSecondFn,
  }
) {
  const firstResult = options.firstFunction();
  return options.secondFunction(firstResult)
}
console.log("working", arrowFunctionsWork(
  {
    firstFunction: () =>  true,
    secondFunction:(arg) => {
      // correctly inferred as boolean
      return arg
    }
  }
))
```

I've reviewed the docs and I cannot seem to find an explanation for this behavior.

Comment: @kaya3 yea good catch, will update the example. thanks.